# Gitlab-ci.yml Configuration

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to run job only when there is merge request to specific branch. I configure .gitlab-ci.yml file as follow

```yaml
stages:
  - test
  - deploy

test:
  stage: test
  only: 
  - develop
  - merge_requests

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  only: 
  - master
  - merge_requests
```

This will even run job deploy when merge request is for develop branch. How can I configure gitlab-ci.yml file so that when there is merge request for develop, test job will run and when there is merge request for master, deploy job will run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rules` for this case, by making gitlab-ci execute the job when there is a merge request targeting a specific branch like below

```
stages:
  - test
  - deploy

test:
  stage: test
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "develop"'
      when: always

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "master"'
      when: always
```

For more information check out [the docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/#rules)

Answer (score 0):

try changing merge_request to merge_requests. The docs suggest using merge_requests, so I feel a typo is what is causing this issue for you.

[gitlab ci docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/merge_request_pipelines/)

Comment: It will run both job when there is merge request to branch develop.

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-advanced. It seems like only should match after and-ing master and merge_requests

Comment: try adding refs: as a child of only: and -master and -merge_requests as child of refs: